# Does iCloud Photos support CR2/DNG raw?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I imported a folder of photos in Canon CR2 and DNG raw format into Photos.app. They show up fine locally in the app (I can edit them), but they don't upload to iCloud. Ordinary JPG files in the same folder upload successfully. The RAW images were shot without corresponding JPGs, ie the CR2 and DNG images are the only copy.

Are CR2/DNG unsupported by iCloud, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: If you are on a Mac, open terminal and type file and then drop one on, it will fingerprint it or you might want to add the exit data to show which version of canon raw file is in play. The file extension usually hides some important data on compatibility. Camera model can sometimes be a proxy for file format as well.

Comment: fyi the camera models involved are Canon 400D and Canon 5D Mk2, but I don't think that's an issue as I can find working examples of uploads of images from both cameras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's working, I think it's still uploading them but the progress bar in Photos.app is missing. I looked at the total number of items visible at https://www.icloud.com/photos and the number is gradually going up. They're slower to appear on iPhone but I do see some RAW photos there, based on a random check.

The progress bar is now working and the "Uploading 445 items" counter is slowly going up instead of down, so it looks like it's slow to decide what it needs to upload. There's now only 6324 large RAW files left to upload.

Comment: I'd guess that the upload simply takes longer due to increased file size per image.

Comment: It even took a while for Photos to figure out how many it wanted to upload, hence my confusion at the start. Now the progress bar has stabilised and it's uploading RAWs at a consistent rate.